# VSTO Add-In to automatically export custom PowerPoint slide shows

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

One of the groups in my company works on a very large PowerPoint slide deck.  Not all of the slides in this deck are relevant to everyone.  The purpose of this deck is to have a singular source of material which people can pick and choose slides depending the type of presentation that is needed.  The slide deck has a number of pre-defined custom slide shows to make this process easier.

While this solution works well in many cases, we need a simple way to quickly export a Custom Show to a new presentation.  I'm aiming to develop a VSTO add-in that will allow a user to select one or more custom slide shows and then export the slide shows to their desktop and I'm looking for some code to help get me on my way.

Does anyone know how to export an existing Custom Show to a new presentation?  Better yet, is there a way to allow users to select and export one or more existing shows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question, I've wanted to do this myself for a long time, so took the time to figure it out for you (and me!).

Basically, you'll want to a) loop through all `NamedSlideShows`, b) find their slides by `SlideID`, c) add a new presentation and then d) copy over the `NamedSlideShow` slides with the original design. You can do this for one or all Custom Shows, based on how you send in the commands.

Here's an example:

```vb
Sub FindShows()
    Dim p As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set p = PowerPoint.ActivePresenation
    Dim cShow As PowerPoint.NamedSlideShow
    For Each cShow In p.SlideShowSettings.NamedSlideShows
        SaveCustomShow (cShow.Name, p)
        'If using PowerPoint 2010 use the following line instead:
        'SaveCustomShow cShow.Name, p
    Next
End Sub
```

The `FindShows` sub just finds all Custom Shows in the `ActivePresentation` and sends them to a routine that will create the each new presenation based on the specified Custom Show name. You can customize this as needed.

This routine below is the heart of it. There are a couple of things to note:

- To send over the slide design of the
  source slide, you have to explicity
  set the copied slide to use that
  design.
- A `NamedSlideShow` will only give you
  the `SlideID` of the slides within it.
  You can use `FindBySlideID` to then
  identify that slide in the original
  presentation - it returns a slide
  object. Then you simply copy it and
  paste it with the design of the
  original.

```vb
    Sub SaveCustomShow(showName As String, p As Presentation)
        Dim cShows As PowerPoint.NamedSlideShows
        Set cShows = p.SlideShowSettings.NamedSlideShows
        Dim cSlideIDs As Variant
        cSlideIDs = cShows(showName).SlideIDs
        Dim destinationPath As String
        destinationPath = "C:\Temp\"
        Dim newP As PowerPoint.Presentation
        Set newP = PowerPoint.Presentations.Add(WithWindow:=False)
        With newP
            .SaveAs destinationPath & cShows(showName).Name
            Dim s As PowerPoint.Slide
            Dim e As Integer
            For e = 1 To UBound(cSlideIDs)
                Set s = p.Slides.FindBySlideID(SlideID:=cSlideIDs(e))
                s.Copy
                .Slides.Paste.Design = s.Design
            Next
           .Save
           .Close
        End With
        Set newP = Nothing
    End Sub
```

There's not any error checking in the code, so that will need to be worked out, but it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

This works a treat!
careful to create a copy of the file first!

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00893.htm